# Docker --volume does not mount folder into nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to learn some docker commands ( without Dockerfile and I am on ubuntu). I use this command first:

```
docker container run -p 80:80 nginx:latest
```

Then inside my browser when I open http://192.168.99.100 ( which is my virtualmachine IP), it shows default page for nginx.

Then I stop the container and try this command:

```
dock container run --volume /home/mazoo/DockerExampleFolder/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 nginx:latest
```

I open in my brwoser http://192.168.99.100 and I receive 403 Forbidden error. My console shows:

```
2019/12/16 00:23:56 [error] 6#6: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.99.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.99.100"
```

Also I try http://192.168.99.100/1.html (1.html is a html file inside /home/mazoo/DockerExampleFolder/html folder on my computer which logically should be mounted into container) I receive 404 Not Found error in browser and in my console I see this error:

```
[error] 6#6: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/1.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.99.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /1.html HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.99.100"
```

Error is showing "/usr/share/nginx/html" did not recieve 1.html file from my host into container.

Then I try another path in my container:

```
docker container run --volume /home/mazoo/DockerExampleFolder/html:/var/html -p 80:80 nginx:latest
```

But when I browse http://192.168.99.100 it shows default nginx welcome page ( I have an index.html inside my html folder so I expect default welcome page should overriden) and again for http://192.168.99.100/1.html I receive Not Found error.

Seems for some reasons, my folder does not get mounted into my container.

Answer (score 0):

First start the docker container up with a name:

```
dock container run --name nginx --volume /home/mazoo/DockerExampleFolder/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 nginx:latest
```

Then go inside the running container to explore.

```
docker exec -it nginx bash
```

Check for the expected files and ownerships in /usr/share/nginx/..

I suspect it's a permission issue.

---

Use a named volume:

```
docker rm nginx  ## clean up from earlier, if needed

docker volume create nginx-data

docker run --name nginx --rm -v nginx-data:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx:latest
```

outside the container:

```
cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx-data/_data/
```

Comment: Thanks, seems the files are not there, after run docker exec -it ... and then run ls /usr/share/nginx/html and it shows there is no file there and its empty.

Comment: That would be a problem.   Seems like the right spot, but gotta find a new way to get files there.   Try the named mount method in the updated answer.

Comment: after run cd /var/lib/docker .... I receive permission denied error: bash: cd: /var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx-data/_data/: Permission denied Does that mean docker can not access the files from the host?

Comment: Your login and the docker's service user doesn't have the permission to interop on the same set of files.  Honestly, i'm not sure what the best course of action is at this point.   I would generally mediate the difference using the root user (sudo su -).  But there's probably a better/proper answer out there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this:

Inside Oracle VM VirtualBox shared folder setting, my "home" was mapped as "hosthome" so instead of

```
dock container run --name nginx --volume /home/mazoo/DockerExampleFolder/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 nginx:latest
```

It should be

```
dock container run --name nginx --volume /hosthome/mazoo/DockerExampleFolder/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 nginx:latest
```

Means instead of "home" in the path, it should be "hosthome"

Comment: are you sure its `dock` and not `docker`?